# Why do I get an error "not defined" in EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to translate a page to a certain language, so I have a file called `language.js` with a variable `language_pack` that stores all the translations. I referenced the folder with that file in my server file and proceeded to use `language_pack` in my ejs file only to be told that it is not defined

Code in my server file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
// language_pack is located under a file called language.js 
// under the configurations folder`var 
language_pack = require("../configuration/language.js");
console.log(language_pack)
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Hello World")
  res.render("index", {
    lang: "ms",
    language_pack: language_pack
  });
});
router.get('/MuscleTest', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Hello World")
  res.render("MuscleTest", {
    lang: "ms",
    language_pack: language_pack
  });
});
```

In the language.js file under the configuration folder, language_pack is defined as:

```
var language_pack={ms:{
    fourth_step:"Sit to stand"
}}
```

In my ejs file, at this line, I get a `language_pack` is not defined error when I try to run it.:

```
<h3><%=language_pack[lang]["fourth_step"]%></h3>
```

Comment: Where is your code where you are defining language_pack in node.js?

Comment: Please edit your question, including all relevant code **as text, not images**.

Comment: @spender I added some code and more explanation to the post. Hope this helps

Comment: "language_pack is not defined" error. Is this specifically the wording of the error?

Comment: You forgot to assign anything to `module.exports`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `language.js` should look like below. If you need to import or require something it should be exported in that module (.js).

For more about require: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/

```js
// language.js
module.exports = {
    ms: {
        fourth_step: "Sit to stand"
    }
};
```

Also please correct this,

```
language_pack = require("../configuration/language.js");
```

as

```
const language_pack = require("../configuration/language");
```